# Attached Property Binding not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I created an attached property to set commands using inputbinding on a datagridRow or datagricell in the style of the element.

Here im trying to add inputBinding on thing that are dynamically created such as datagridrows/cells, this is why im trying to add the inputbinding in the style.

Unfortunately the style dont allow me to use the InputBindings property of the datagridrows/cells in xaml and it need to be set in the code this is why i need the attached property.

The attached property propertychangedcallback methode is trigger on each row/cell creation and the methode recive the object on witch the property is set and the value of the property. The value is a input binding collection. In this collection the items are present but property of those item are not bind to their value

In the xaml you can see that I create only one InputBinding for all the rows/cells but I need to copy this Inputbinding on every row because they need their own commandParameter otherwise the commandParameter would be the same for every row/cell

When I remove the InputBindingsCollection and use a single InputBinding it works but i can only set on inputbinding and i want to have a mousebinding and a keybinding so I need to use the InputBindingsCollection.

When I use the InputBindingsCollection the inputBindings of the collection are not bind properly

In the `InputBindingsPropertyChangedCallBack` method the `inpuBind.Command`and `inpuBind.CommandParameter` are  null instead of the binding value

**AttacheCommand**

```
public class AttacheCommand
{
    public static DependencyProperty InputBindingsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InputBindings", 
                                                                                                 typeof(InputBindingCollection),
                                                                                                 typeof(AttacheCommand),
                                                                                                 new PropertyMetadata(InputBindingsPropertyChangedCallBack));
    public static void SetInputBindings(UIElement element, InputBindingCollection value)
    {
        element.SetValue(InputBindingsProperty, value);
    }

    public static InputBindingCollection GetInputBindings(UIElement element)
    {
        return (InputBindingCollection)element.GetValue(InputBindingsProperty);
    }

    public static void InputBindingsPropertyChangedCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = d as UIElement;
        InputBinding copy;
        foreach (InputBinding inpuBind in e.NewValue as InputBindingCollection)
        {
           //*****Here is my problem inpuBind.Command and inpuBind.CommandParameter are not bind to their value and are null
            copy = new InputBinding(inpuBind.Command, inpuBind.Gesture);
            copy.CommandParameter = inpuBind.CommandParameter;

            element.InputBindings.Add(copy);
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="UltimateCommand.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UltimateCommand"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel x:Name="vm"/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding listModel1}" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="local:AttacheCommand.InputBindings" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <InputBindingCollection>
                            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ElementName=vm, Path=cmd1}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Gesture="LeftClick"/>
                        </InputBindingCollection>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel: (and Command)**

```
class ViewModel
{
    public Model1[] listModel1
    {
        get
        {
            return new Model1[] { new Model1("nom1", 1), new Model1("nom2", 2) };
        }
    }

    public Command1 cmd1
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command1();
        }
    }
}

public class Command1 : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Model1 :**

```
public class Model1
{
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Model1(string n, int a)
    {
        Nom = n;
        Age = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have the same problem as this guy (see the marked answer) - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e5def98-d9e0-4afb-80da-1959cf36a8f7/binding-a-command-in-inputbinding?forum=wpf

Comment: OMG, you're doing *so* much unnecessary work here... you don't need to use Attached Properties to set a `MouseBinding` or `KeyBinding` for an `ICommand`. Just use [`RelayCommand`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) instead. Then you can just data bind to the `Command`s from the view model: `<KeyBinding Gesture="CTRL+S" Command="{Binding Save, Mode=OneWay}" />`

Comment: Here im trying too add inputBinding on thing that are dynamiclly created such as datagridrows/cells, this is why i m trying to add the inputbinding in the style, The style dont allow to use the InputBindings property of the datagridrows/cells in xaml and it need to be set in the code and can't use what you said<br>
the attached property propertychangedcallback methode is trigger on each row/cell creation. <br>
In the xaml I create only one InputBinding for all the rows/cells but I need to copy the Inputbinding on every row because they need their own commandParameter but the binding dont work

Answer (score 0):

If i'am talking right the attached property or command Class must be static

so you have to write public static Class AttachedCommand{}

Comment: i tried what you said but it didnt change anything, the binding still not working